# How to login activiti-explorer with authentication of another application's database

Tags: activiti, bpmn, camunda

i have another web application B (obviously which have it's own database).
i want users of application B should use activiti-explorer. so i want authentication from Application B, what approach/steps should i need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your users to LDAP [directory](http://www.openldap.org/) and have both of your applications access that.

Comment: Be aware, the Security Configuration override link provided is only valid for Activiti Enterprise. The basic approach is similar in Community Edition (i.e. implement a custom Userdetails service and register in the SecurityConfiguration class) but the actual interfaces are a little different.

Comment: actually i am using activiti-5.21.0, should i write my own classes to login/ Authentication through application B, and change activitiLoginHandler entry in activiti-login-context.xml? or what steps should i follow to implement custom authentication that would not affect activiti work flow in future.

Comment: I won't suggest to tangle with `ActivitiLoginHandler` unless you know hw it functions. Nevertheless, there are other simple workarounds. Try them first